# Unable to add an image in a rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to add an image in my rails application however getting an error

**Html code in the theme I purchased**

```
<img src="img/tour_plan_4.jpg" alt="" class="rounded-circle thumb_visit">
```

**My code in ERB**

```
<%= image_tag("hashtag.png"), class: "rounded-circle thumb_visit" %>
```

Please help thanks.

Comment: what is the error

Comment: you have to write it like this

`<%= image_tag("hashtag.png", class: "rounded-circle thumb_visit") %>`

You are closing the parenthesis of the helper to early.

Comment: Thanks it helped!!

Answer (score 2):

You don't compare the Rails project & static HTML project, you need to understand the Rails project structure such as rails [`assets pipeline`](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/v5.0/asset_pipeline.html).

If you want to show an image in a Rails project then put images into `app/assets/images/` folder then call from `erb` file as like

```
<%= image_tag("hashtag.png", class: "rounded-circle thumb_visit") %>
```

OR

```
<%= image_tag "hashtag.png", class: "rounded-circle thumb_visit" %>
```

The generated HTML is

```
# => <img src="/assets/hashtag.png" class="rounded-circle thumb_visit" />
```

or other many ways to call images in Rails projects, you just need to understand the Rails project structure.

see the [`image_tag`](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper/image_tag) helper

Answer (score 1):

according to your comment it's just a syntax error. Try this:

```
<%= image_tag("hashtag.png", class: "rounded-circle thumb_visit") %>
```

from [image_tag docs](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper/image_tag)